# SPSS: using char.substr in macro / Split String into multiple variables (macro)

Tags: macros, spss, substr

I am trying to write a macro that extracts a defined part of strings stored in a variable. As I intend to use the macro on different variables, I pass the variable from which I get the string as an argument to my macro.
My Problem is that `char.substr()` does not work in macros and `!SUBSTR` won't work as expected, because it does not take a substring of the variable values. Instead it takes a substring of the variable name.

If I pass VAR1 as an argument to my macro it throws an error, because it subsets VAR1 to "VA" and then tries to assign the values of a (non-existing) variable "VA" to OUT2. At least I guess that's the problem.

If anybody could help me, I would really appreciate it :)

(What I am actually trying to achieve is to wirte a macro function that splits a user defined variable that contains a string into different variables based on a delimiter. Within this macro I need the `!SUBSTR` function. That's why I chose my example the way I did. But if you know a solution to my real problem without providing a solution to the substring problem, you're welcome too :D)

```
* DEFINE DATA. 

DATA LIST /ID 1-3 VAR1 (A10).
BEGIN DATA
001 abc
002 defgh
003 ijkl
END DATA.

* NON-MACRO CODE (works).

STRING OUT1 (A10).
COMPUTE OUT1 = char.substr(VAR1, 1, 2).
EXECUTE. 

* MACRO CODE (does not work).

DEFINE crt_substr (var = !TOKENS(1)).
    STRING OUT2 (A10).
    COMPUTE OUT2 = !SUBSTR(VAR1,1,2).
!ENDDEFINE.

crt_substr var=VAR1.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, there is no reason not to use `char.substr` within a macro, when you actually want to read substrings from your data (`!substr` only changes the syntax created by the macro).

So in your example - this works fine (note a few corrections to your macro syntax):

```
DEFINE crt_substr (vr = !TOKENS(1)).
    STRING OUT2 (A10).
    COMPUTE OUT2 = char.SUBSTR(!vr,1,2).
!ENDDEFINE.

crt_substr vr=var1.
EXECUTE.
```

All this being said, you don't necessarily need a macro to split a string with a delimiter - you can use `loop` in regular syntax, [take a look here](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-split-string-variable-into-separate-variables/) for a nice tutorial.
[This](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/making-multiple-string-variables-single-multiply-coded-field) is another example of doing it with a macro.

Comment: thank you. your code works. now I am wondering why `char.substr()` didn't work for me before (or why I was thinking it did not work) ... but I guess there was another syntax error that sabotaged my code :D (which corrections did you make to my macro syntax? ... except from changing var to vr? and using `char.substr`?)

Comment: and thanks for the link to the tutorial on "Splitting a String Variable". I knew that post before and my original goal was to convert this syntax into a macro syntax (I am trying to build a standard syntax that reads a file and - in the process - transforms all variables that contain information about mutliple selections to dummy variables. using a macro I just tried to reduce the total number of lines). Unfortunately it seems that the substr function was not the only part of this macro that did not work :P

Comment: I changed `var` to `vr` because `var` is used as a subcommand in some SPSS funtions so you shouldn't use it as a variable name or macro argument name (along with words like "to", "mean" etc'). Another correction to the syntax was changing `SUBSTR(VAR1,1,2)` to `SUBSTR(!vr,1,2)`. You were accepting the name "VAR1" as a macro argument, but not using it - so whatever varibale name you entered into the macro, it was always working on "VAR1". Your project sounds interesting - keep at it and we'll be glad to help with more questions!

Comment: aaah ... i missed the !vr part, thanks :)
in the meantime I tried to find a working solution for my task, but in the process my code threw so many errors, that I feel beaten black and blue ^^ ... if you could take a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527471/spss-macro-split-string-into-multiple-variables) it would be a great help :)

Comment: I saw that other post, but it is problematic - Stack-Overflow code doesn't allow you to just present a task and ask answerers to write code for you - you need to focus on a specific problem, show what you tried and what happened, what error messages you got etc'. That's the way we can help - one step at a time (like you did in this question)

Comment: I understand that point. And usually I use stackoverflow in this way ... with SPSS error messages I have problem to narrow down the problem ... but I will try my best and be mor specific :)